# zipgrep to get uniques lines and their counts

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I am find unique occurrence of lines with count using following command from zip file

```
zipgrep "Error code" log-backup-05_11_2013_01_04.zip | sort | uniq -c
```

It's showing me separate count of every file included in zip file but i want count of whole zip file.

Problem which i am looking is due to file name in start of every line.

How we can ignore filename and just check uniquesness on the base of content?

```
158 data/log/ffe/log-backup-05_11_2013_01_04/ffe1.log.2013-11-04-01:Message Error code [61040] Error Description 
60 data/log/ffe/log-backup-05_11_2013_01_04/ffe1.log.2013-11-04-01:Message Error code [61440] Error Description  

150 data/log/ffe/log-backup-05_11_2013_01_04/ffe1.log.2013-11-04-02:Message Error code [61040] Error Description 
66 data/log/ffe/log-backup-05_11_2013_01_04/ffe1.log.2013-11-04-02:Message Error code [61440] Error Description `
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have any `:` in your filenames, try

```
zipgrep "Error code" log-backup-05_11_2013_01_04.zip | sed 's/[^:]*://' | sort | uniq -c
```

This cuts away everything up to the first occurrence of `:`.

Comment: i tried following     zipgrep "Error code" log-backup-05_11_2013_01_04.zip | cut -d':' -f 2- | sort | uniq -c

Comment: [tag:cut] works as well, I usually prefer [tag:sed]. [tag:awk] would be another option.